# How to use FileReference to Play sound?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

I build a flex application to play a sound. I use FileReference to browse mp3 file. How can I use that FileReference object to play that file using Sound Class's play method. Or I can load data from that FileReference Object into a byteArray. Can that byteArray be played using Sound Class? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using FileReference to load an mp3 file into a Sound object then it won't play correctly because the data is compressed (audio will be noise).

Anyway there is an alternative library of code that also solves your problem...:
http://flexiblefactory.co.uk/flexible/?p=46

Inside the article you will also find a link to this zip file:
http://www.flexiblefactory.co.uk/flexible/wp-content/uploads/mp3filereferenceloaderlib.zip

I don't use Flex but to setup in Flash CS I would go into the zip file and copy the org folder files to my project folder (as subfolder) and then have the code below in .as file and also an FLA that is the stage.

You also need to create three sprites or MovieCips to use as buttons.

- File Open  (instance-name: btn_open)
- Play       (instance-name: btn_play)
- Stop       (instance-name: btn_stop)

*** AS3 CODE ***

```
package  
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

import org.audiofx.mp3.MP3FileReferenceLoader;
import org.audiofx.mp3.MP3SoundEvent;


public class MP3_fileRef_test extends MovieClip 

{
    private var loader:MP3FileReferenceLoader;
    private var fileReference:FileReference;
    public var _loadedsound:Sound = new Sound;
    public var channel_obj:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
    public var mp3_isPlaying:Boolean;


    public function MP3_fileRef_test() 
    {
        mp3_isPlaying = false;

        btn_open.buttonMode = true;
        btn_open.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mp3Open_handler);

        btn_play.buttonMode = true;
        btn_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, audio_play);

        btn_stop.buttonMode = true;
        btn_stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, audio_stop);

        loader = new MP3FileReferenceLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(MP3SoundEvent.COMPLETE, mp3Loader_Complete);

        fileReference=new FileReference();
        fileReference.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,fileReferenceSelectHandler);
    }

    //OPEN BROWSE WINDOW & TRIGGER EVENT FUNCTION fileReferenceSelectHandler 
    private function mp3Open_handler (ev:MouseEvent):void
    {
        fileReference.browse( [new FileFilter("mp3 files","*.mp3")] );
    }

    private function fileReferenceSelectHandler(e:Event):void
    {
        loader.getSound(fileReference);
    }

    private function mp3Loader_Complete (loader_mp3Data:MP3SoundEvent):void
    {
        //CHECK IF THERE'S A PREVIOUSLY OPENED FILE PLAYING
        //OTHERWISE WILL BE MULTIPLE SOUNDS PLAYING OVER EACH OTHER
        if (mp3_isPlaying == true)
        {
            channel_obj.stop();
            mp3_isPlaying = false;
        }

        _loadedsound = new Sound;
        _loadedsound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoad_Complete);

        //PUT (MP3SoundEvent) LOADER DATA INTO NEW _loadedsound SOUND OBJECT
        _loadedsound = loader_mp3Data.sound;

        //UNLOCK BELOW FOR AUTO-START WITHOUT PRESSING PLAY BUTTON
        //channel_obj = _loadedsound.play(); //auto
        //mp3_isPlaying = true; //auto
    }

    //WHEN SOUND IS LOADED AND READY FOR USE
    function soundLoad_Complete(e:Event):void
    {
        //Do whatever else is needed on successful  load
        //eg: trace or update status text, make an MC visible etc
    }

    //PLAY AUDIO ON CLICK
    function audio_play (e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if (mp3_isPlaying == false)
        {
            channel_obj = _loadedsound.play();
            mp3_isPlaying = true;
        }
    }

    //STOP AUDIO ON CLICK   
    function audio_stop (e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if (mp3_isPlaying == true)
        {
            channel_obj.stop();
            mp3_isPlaying = false;
        }
    }


}//END CLASS

}//END PACKAGE
```

Hope it helps. Peace I'm outta here....

Comment: The links are dead, but I found the source code in the following link: https://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/source/browse/trunk/projects/FluidSolver3D/src/?r=91#src%2Forg%2Faudiofx%2Fmp3

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. First you load an mp3 from FileReference, then you instantiate `new Sound()`, then call `loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(loadedBytes,loadedBytes.length)` and then play it. Don't forget to rewind the ByteArray in question to starting position, if it isn't done by FileReference, as this function uses current position as starting for the file.

[The manual.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#loadCompressedDataFromByteArray%28%29)

Update: If you are using Flash player 10, this method is unavailable. For this, try creating an `URLRequest` out of `FileReference.name`, and then loading the sound via this forged request.

```
var ur:URLRequest=new URLRequest(fileRef.name);
var snd:Sound=new Sound(ur);
snd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,sndLoaded);
```

Then you process loaded sound as ready.

Comment: I can not find this method, when I try to call Sound Class methods. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am using sdk 3.6. Is this the reason I can not use this API of Sound Class?

Comment: Hmm, it says it was introduced in FP11 and AIR 3.